# Node, Angular, RecordRTC - saving uploaded video blob to disk

Tags: angularjs, express, file-upload, recordrtc

I want to write an uploaded Video+Audio blob to disk on a node server.
The blob was generated by RecordRTC after recording the stream and I use Angular's $http.post to send the video blob along with some other identifying data to the server as below

```
// localStreamRecorder is an instance of RecordRTC
self.localStreamRecorder.getDataURL(function(dataUrl) {
    var data = {
        call_id: 'USR009',
        media: dataUrl
    };
    $http.post('/api/recorded_call', data)
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

On the server side, I am able to access the blob but I am unable to write the blob as a valid video file using the code below.

```
app.route('/api/recorded_call')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        fs.writeFile('video-'+req.body.user_id, req.body.media,
            function(err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                res.send({ 'success': true });
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there anyway I can write the blob (media attribute of req.body) as a valid video file to disk for later access and viewing?

[EDIT]
I have included the log showing the output of req.body below (media attribute shortened)

```
{ call_id: '161f25090811617F62CD62',
  media: 'data:audio/webm;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKEd2VibUKHgQRChYECGFOAZwH/////////FUmpZpkq17GDD0JATYCGQ2hyb21lV0GGQ2hyb21lFlSua7+uvdeBAXPFh5ekuYmhmlqDgQKGhkFfT1BVU2Oik09wdXNIZWFkAQEAAIC7AAAAAADhjbWERzuAAJ+BAWJkgRAfQ7Z1Af/////////ngQCjQh+
BAACA+4PfkcoFL7c9XEormBZ3dLyTnMQQn2YnFE9bYuzBo+L0kXK1ttvkEhn2s7fbuLJzIpRZ5Z2CZM8d5HJ4MNnupGB3DeRV/S9K86keLStaGDzpe4bl9+GcEF8RiyqQbl84TE3HLCJqusEf/voXH+IZ4wm3YT1oFY8ai0PZtdnLqwzdyqUDGCVZGFMqM4swwp5765bzjWL10e7TN6UTelJ2/1VbZ1/WvUzvo1bok7S+En7XuQcBJElINlZ
Lyx4hXAnMkV+9YkDfQ0tc2hen6VJVBBPG9mQOqFkqPrB02H6u825KRpewZSwtYYe4QXxDuaniEAYAHUcB6IlTqwKFyqdj4+YUJ5ns4MuB4aPrcWMPGrtqnjG36NWdF9wXeUfOm4khp2dI0v92r+OooYkKdZc9+93as6Nhs5WIvCX3yvPQoNj5tIuOwYqjehyajW1vKWj4NIAUztA4T5y8VKsql+wE9Xf6cqQuTsS1+GK40SPLtmLXtqjQrbb
HUKSACCK7k0Slyx3J2QjjPuf+hUqdWHf+t6nCy1rL3VBMl5lKckDnP1QtiD856bhDMnOFU8D8vbVQo0L6r+36aoj1FRvvcwL358ZDd7ZwON1IGSAcOyqsd+Sm3gY0pZz1szK+sw7wT3XcIrwhcFJoZ9CJobiuUUH7BjctQZeD7QdyAg4Jo0Q8XRNH3vuAvtNf7g4+vQ4y3pMVbEf6rd8hHEqEQtOjQd+BADqA+4Ohnj78P+m+jwU6gSooyzz
XPm2dLXozekKQslYBi+xyATgu7NWyUw9bqHcZSW24qtnFejnR/t2eAhwv5v98IHFcfJMH3hc9/vMbDV7zAoMiOvki0plKEiP7v0gQ7naRCQdiV2Vf4XWW7YzV8VUzCMLyq2Iu1eacvZzG5T6AE58NvxnkJoxR35Z9T/Zt6z+ODoabsIQ1cTb9W07vNEhNxaMBR15zxaLPWHdVLzQQHrE9ThAT/XUk6cSRIJ836N7n5jsE8pvmYc74gY0yOb8
N1klxFgfDEvnfo2Bv8j+ybY+TI5j3xTOOFv22WhVs5N4dL3aT+nTSm/+IaqF+glvq+KbgQFn74U5l2TnLveW04iRh5XS4iFXizAM4BRTRKcw6K0Irgj6abCeaItT3Q7UlDN2wcTTSkZdTi04Av4dUp7tt/SjHAqrYhjJ4qLuTpj/b/ViKml1rWLx9HA0vM0efvVHHYfS/Bh4GUmcVGCR5YS+SPMCwGkdEKI8+yuEAqSnC7ox0Fz0vhE5DxBs
2/DjCM1ddhAzGTaykzfF+yjOyceFEGqMsskrv4wbUZwpeIgK8Fhd5B/PNRwvrm0Rz0Qz0U8b/8PZPR6XENtGxS67tKlkottsAaoE6LNYRLaNBz4EAeID7g5OXsE3XrascqeR3oq+lbsBoM6wKq9Q8ire0O5rMPhAPGTnxnqBdM9gSRiq+L6txYm6Ap5to6fyNXTeg2kKqM8dbJXnmvwC7Ka7TeAZXH3xlKOqu7tvy96YGd/1gGKIIrbmYu4+
nAwecjA25u5lHQjylJlYLyKP+5gq2hXcmMkTRNu0dNH/DRH7o3u7wrTIKnp/kbBEZrxivzoyiulisYXurFovW4N8EMP3b89RnBWAhSrE+Zhokp8wc9WOaiC9VYoVM0QqJCgARCgBMHqUHKSxlEvD24cphvjXOPnqqbtr5OQ051Hrcjp80mKsJYkYfJWUQTuAGFyzzaKK+nFMkxpOnJ11LqJWTbx1GCrMz8QuOCzTwbcMWqHu8IbHabbSoWNj
Ef0AFmDKtg3U+WsLEWMGmj/dZDVfi5ExF4YzJpV59O5UyefP+CMboBKmHfdhh2b6LHAXROvqXccFLq601Hk1FepCPABAtVb87//IHZYqZmnySWeGsD3hDF/FCJd9OB9CGub9TGLyteVr0Xy4kQLqV3PC617XFFtXbE/g6LdamhG840rrKbpNP+NVLB8ROlEKWdbyFSPowy1Q0nRUR/jUPKhzjVcIy2bijQdOBALOA+4OYk8W7Iaoa/jl51nh
uS0yR0ByN3Jj/mc0hJlt3icdl4AhLSEMJD0mhI3lQOwdZxwOfyfEPVhSqstkjXoSOGYSS3x7dXyULWiBxnia+ZMuToGNwFC6i8nOugJPNWM/8epSx76tHZkf7Jju8A4Vpr26vOxXp944LNhAMG5vKTsWflpzgRA6FTpwYKIpwHtXU6AIKnnK+CbqW1Ba5wO6OTYtXT72d688qlT5tzcOoCWc1eVSTiC/W3Zb2jzEFqi2tBmDnyxj5Kx0ghvg
}
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: No, there is none.

Comment: So the file is written to disk, but is corrupted data?

Comment: Yes. No video player can play the written files

Comment: Hmm maybe specify the encoding? fs.writeFile(fileName, data, 'base64', callback);

Comment: It does not work, even adding the extension to the filename. I checked out the metadata of the written files with VLC and each has nothing(codecs, metadata) except the filenames

Comment: Adding the extension wouldn't change anything.  Did you try specifying the encoding?

Comment: Yes, base 64 as in the command in your third comment above